# Find rows not fitting datetime format in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-cleaning

Apologies if this question has been asked already. I thought it would but I have not been able to find an answer. I want to convert a column in pandas dataframe to datetime format

```
import pandas as pd 
df['DateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

and apparently some rows contain other characters

```
ValueError: time data 0000-00-00 doesn't match format specified
```

Now the df is quite large so that visual inspection of all unique values does not work (and I would also like to learn how to do it without looking through all values). I would like to find out all the unique values that do not fit the specified format, so that I can then clean them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'`, so wrong format generate missing values, then filter original values and convert to unique lists by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce').isna()

print (df.loc[m, 'DateOfBirth'].unique().tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks!! And quite surprised to see that pandas even checks whether dates make sense beyond formatting:
['0000-00-00', '1070-06-08', '2971-10-29', '1083-07-04', '0985-08-01', '1070-07-17']

Comment: @Felix - yop, it return all dates outside possible minimal and maximal Timestamp in pandas - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations)